# Replication fails exactly after a week

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, windows-server

We are application developers trying to decode why replication is failing.

It fails every week on the same day pretty much same time.

This has been happening for about a month now and our vendors are not helping with any answers.

Where should we start with diagnostics?

Comment: What else happens at that time?

Comment: There is a checkDB job that runs for almost an hour.

Comment: Can you try running that at a different time to see if the two are correlated?

Comment: That is something we want to try doing. But is there anything else, any diagnostic queries to check the sql server performance

Comment: jxs5455 - What is the status on this? Did you ever find a solution or were any of the answers below sufficient to help resolve your problem in a satisfactory manner?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check [subscription expiration option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151188.aspx) or check replication monitor for the error in more details, this can help, resolving your problem.

Comment: What error you get in replication monitor when it fails? Screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Max's comments about running the stuff that would normally run when the issue occurs as a simple step to confirm whether or not those items/processes are causing the issue -- process of elimination should be simple enough.

Since you pretty much have the day and timing down to a science when the issue occurs, you could schedule a SQL profiler trace to run via a SQL agent job and give it a stop time (@stoptime) to stop the trace to see what details the trace will provide.

Since you asked about where else you could start to troubleshoot, I think a SQL profiler trace would give you a lot of detail to go by actually.

I'll paste what I have on this when I did it on SQL Server 2008 R2 below.

**SETUP DETAILS**

Follow the below instructions for scheduling a trace with a *specific start time* and a *specific end time*.

You'll go to *'SQL Server Profiler'* and build your trace criteria as usual but be sure to save to a file somewhere valid on the server itself, check the *'enable file rollover'* option, and specify a trace stop time.

Once all the criteria is selected and filtered for what you need to capture, run it, stop it, and then navigate. . .

**FILE | EXPORT | SCRIPT TRACE DEFINITION |** *'select'* the **SQL Server 2005 - 2008 R2** | and then *save the file somewhere you can open later*.

Go to the file, open it and you should get something similar to the below.

**KEY POINTS**

- **schedule this with a SQL Agent job for when you want it to start**
- **specify in the SET @DateTime variable the correct time and date it
  should stop**

You can also run this adhoc this way without SQL Agent scheduling specifying the correct DateTime variable when you want it to stop.

Once the process has run, you just go to the file and open it as usual.
See script logic at bottom with comments on how to confirm this isn't running any longer, etc. -- any traces for that matter and how to stop them from running if they are.

**NOTE:** In my case we scheduled this job start with SQL Agent job at 7 AM and then put the DateTime variable value for the @stoptime argument passed to the sp_trace_create object so it quit running at 8 AM on this day. Once in the office and reviewing this, we were able to sift through and determine the issue and correct. We filtered our trace criteria down as much as we could though beforehand when we built the script file that saves to disk to give the TSQL for scheduling.

```
/****************************************************/
/* Created by: SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler          */
/* Date: 03/11/2015  09:32:00 PM         */
/****************************************************/


-- Create a Queue
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
declare @DateTime datetime

set @DateTime = '2015-03-12 08:00:00.000'
set @maxfilesize = 5

-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'R:\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Traces\dbname.trc', @maxfilesize, @Datetime
if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 17, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 16, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 13, 12, @on


-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 650fcb88-32b9-48be-961d-6fb96a9783e2'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 35, 0, 6, N'%dbname%'
-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

**CONFIRM AND STOP RUNNING TRACES**

```
--- Select the records from the msdb system table
--- status of 1 means it's running
--- status of 0 means it's not running
--- There is a system trace that runs all the time so don't try to stop it

--- Basically just execute the sp_trace_setstatus SP and pass in the first argument as the ID from the select query
--- Pass the second argument for either needing it to stop or run per the above of what those values should be
--- If you want to delete a trace, you have to pass in the second argument as 2 which means stop and delete the record
----- EXAMPLE: exec sp_trace_setstatus 2, 2

select * from sys.traces


exec sp_trace_setstatus 2, 0
```